# CHM Creator with ability to parse html meta keywords

Tags: chm

I have lots of scanned images of a magazine(published monthly) and i have to organize it in searchable manner.
User should be able to view magazine issue wise or can search for predefined categories/keywords.

What i have thought for now, is to create CHM as it will need less effort than creating a new custom built software.
For that i will create seperate HTMl page(Programatically) with image embedded in it along with the keywords(Stored in Excel sheet along with path of Image) for which that image should be included in result.

So i want a chm creator that can parse html meta tags and add keywords in chm keywords list.

One such software i have found is [Abee CHM Maker](http://abeetech.com/chmmakerpro/index.htm)
But i need some free alternative.

If you have any other idea to organize it with minimal efforts, then also you are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

The standard (free) way to create chm files is using Microsoft's HTML help workshop:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms670169(v=vs.85).aspx

Kind regards,
Bo

Answer (score 0):

[Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org) has a CHM creator package, a html DOM implementation and a basic commandline compiler for CHM projects (.hhp). The creator package is independent of MS tools or any other binary blob, and available in source. It is portable as far as FPC is portable (not as portable as gcc on paper, but enough in practice with all major architectures and OSes supported)

One could make something like that, I made something similar, but instead of meta, I folded back titles into TOC and index and cleaned up html (TeX4ht output) and fixed links before turning it into a chm.

But it will require some work, and if you are not familiar with Object Pascal/Delphi (the language), it might be a bridge too far. (the hours required would not compare favorably with the costs of the Abee thing, if that would suit your goals).

On the other hand, in a freely programmable system you can decide yourself how far you automatize things. I put in a lot of work once, and now all new output of tex4ht (with a certain fixed set of settings) formats nicely to chms.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you (it certainly does what you need):

KEL CHM Creator: http://dumah7.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/kel-chm-creator-v-1-4-0-0/

Alternatively, I think you could add tags on each picture (right click on it-> Properties->Details->Tags) and use Windows explorer for searching them. I have never done this but it is supposed to be working (I guess).